# Fill spaces of a column with linear series for entire column

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a column of data that contains spaces randomly throughout it's length, the amount of spaces grouped together is also random. e.g.

```
1                                 1
Space                          1.25
Space                           1.5
Space                          1.75
2                                 2
3                                 3
4                                 4
5                                 5
6                                 6
Space                   6.333333333
Space                   6.666666667
7       Changes to -->            7
8                                 8
9                                 9
Space                           9.5
10                               10
11                               11
12                               12
Space                          12.5
13                               13
Space                   13.33333333
Space                   13.66666667
Space                            14
Space                   14.33333333
Space                   14.66666667
15                               15
```

In a normal situation with a small amount of rows the approach would be to start at the top of the group and manually highlight each space range along with the two values above and below, then apply a linear trend series to populate each empty cell.

The problem is I have up to 20000 rows to process so cannot approach it manually.

Is it possible to somehow apply the series autofill only to the spaces of the entire column?

Comment: I'd say this is trivial-ish to do with scripting, but probably not possible in vanilla Excel. Have you considered writing a small VBA macro to do what you want?

Answer (score 0):

With data like this:

[image]

First click on any cell in the column you wish to process and run this macro:

```
Sub FillInTheBlanks()
    Dim iCol As Long, Last As Long, i As Long
    Dim iBlank As Long, BlankMode As Boolean
    Dim Delta, j As Long, i1 As Long

    iCol = ActiveCell.Column
    Last = Cells(Rows.Count, iCol).End(xlUp).Row
    iBlank = 0
    BlankMode = False

    For i = 1 To Last
        If BlankMode Then
            If Cells(i, iCol) = "" Then
                iBlank = iBlank + 1
            Else
                Delta = (Cells(i, iCol).Value - v1) / (iBlank + 1)
                For j = i1 To i - 1
                    Cells(j, iCol).Value = Cells(j - 1, iCol).Value + Delta
                Next j
                BlankMode = False
            End If
        Else
            If Cells(i, iCol) = "" Then
                v1 = Cells(i - 1, iCol).Value
                iBlank = 1
                i1 = i
                BlankMode = True
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

To produce:

[image]

Comment: I've been working on my own solution and really enjoyed the problem solving process, it's hilarious how elegant your solution is compared to mine though.

Comment: I've been working on my own solution and really enjoyed the problem solving process, it's hilarious how elegant your solution is compared to mine though. My solution uses an additional eight columns filled with nested If statements to identify, filter, compute, combine and store before I use a very basic Macro to move down the column filling each empty cell. My brain is obviously working in a very linear fashion. Thanks for your answer, I'm looking forward to understanding your trail of thought.